# Is it possible to send funds to a scriptAddress using a lightweight wallet?

Tags: wallet, nami-wallet, yoroi, datum, script-addresses

I would like that an user using **Yoroi/Nami/etc** could send funds to a script address which expected an empty datum: `()`.

EDIT (Pretty obvious, but the UTxO should be spendable later by a transaction)

I guess that this is possible using **cardano-cli**, however, could an user do that with a lightweight wallet at the time being?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This answer will surely age fast.

At the time of writing both Nami V3.2.0 and Yoroi Nightly 4.11.501 allow you send to script address, but neither advertise any options of setting datums. Nami allows you to add a note, but that's just for the Tx metadata.

The transactions will succeed, and display in blockchain explorers such as cardanoscan. However the outputs will be stranded: **no datum at a script address ==> stranded.**

Interestingly, these seem to never make it into the chain-index db. Since they are unspendable this is sensible.

For the time being you'll need the Tx to be built using something like the cardano-serialization-lib or equivalent and handed over to the wallet.